# how to destroy activity and show fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity which has a navigation drawer and a framelayout container to show different fragments. On my navigation drawer there is an option which launches another activity(lockpattern activity) to show a lockpattern (had to use activity cause the library doesn't support fragments yet. [Link to Library](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/)).
Once the user has set up his pattern or canceled the procedure,i want the lockpattern activity to get destroyed and show the previous mainActivity and the same fragment what was there in the container before the lockpattern activity was launched.The problem im facing is that once the backbutton is pressed or even if i call the `finish()` function,it doesn't show the previous activity(ie Main activity) but instead relaunches the lockpattern activity.i have even tried `super.onBackPressed();` and it doesn't seem to work.Any help or ideas to get around this is gratefully accepted.

Code of Lockpattern

```
public class Create_Pattern extends Activity {
private static final int REQ_CREATE_PATTERN = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // This is your preferred flag
    LockPatternView.MATRIX_WIDTH = 4;
    Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN,
            null, getBaseContext(), LockPatternActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CREATE_PATTERN: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            char[] pattern = data
                    .getCharArrayExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN);
            DataBaseHandler handler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
            handler.open();

            String PatternToWrite = new String(pattern);
            handler.createPattern(PatternToWrite);
            handler.close();
            Log.d("DEBUG", new String(pattern));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pattern Recorded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();

        }
        break;
    }// REQ_CREATE_PATTERN

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Intent that points to the Activity you want to navigate to next, start that activity by calling startActivity(intent).  Then you can call finish() to destroy the current Activity.

Another approach, (which I have not tried yet) is to create an 'up button' hierarchy and manually call NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

Documentation:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html